# How to have a CustomValidator(using JS) Validate OnBlur or OnChange

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

I am currently using a CustomValidator that uses JavaScript to validate either/or textbox has numbers in it. When I satisfy the validation the error, the message does not clear until submit. How can I fix this so it clears like my other out of the box validators? I am using ASP.NET with C#.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

               function testnumbers(source, args) {
                   var s1 = document.getElementById('<%=arubaBox.ClientID%>').value; var s2 = document.getElementById('<%=shipBox.ClientID%>').value;


                   if (s1 == "" && s2 == "")

                       args.IsValid = false;
                   else if (s1 == "" && s2 != "")

                       args.IsValid = true;
                   else if (s1 != "" && s2 == "")

                       args.IsValid = true;
                   else if (s1 != "" && s2 !== "") args.IsValid = true;

               }

        </script>



   <asp:TextBox ID="aBox" runat="server" MaxLength="7"></asp:TextBox>



  <asp:CustomValidator 
    ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"                       ClientValidationFunction="testnumbers" 
    ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"
     ValidationGroup="Contact"
     Text=" Please provide A # or Shipping Account #" 
    CssClass="errormessage"
     Display="Dynamic" >
    </asp:CustomValidator>

 &nbsp<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
        id="RegularExpressionValidator1"
        runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Field not valid!"
        ControlToValidate="aBox"
        ValidationExpression="[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,}"
        ValidationGroup="Contact"
         />&nbsp

 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
    ID="NumErrAru" 
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="aBox"
     CssClass="errormessage" 
     ErrorMessage=" Numbers Only"
     ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+$"
     ValidationGroup="Contact" 
    Display="Dynamic" 
    Text=" Numbers Only">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control your page validation using both the Page_ClientValidate method and the Page_Validators collection:

```
function jsValidation(){
    Page_ClientValidate();
    $.each(Page_Validators, function(key, value) { 
        if( value.IsValid == false) {
            //- error in validation, locate failing input control 
            var oE = value.ControlToValidate; 
            //- you can for example set focus back to it, if needed
            oE.focus();
        }
    });
}
```

Use [blur](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/blur#fn) event to call your function when element loses focus :

```
$('#<%=element.ClientID%>').blur(function() {   jsValidation(); });
```

This implementation uses jQuery and hasn't been tested but should work pretty much as is.
and you can also simply remove the jQuery interaction and use classical js if needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have been trying to get that to work for the past hour and i am sure it is me and not your code. But i cannot get either to work. would the controltovalidate be <%=abox.ClientID%>. Could you maybe Plug in what i would need from the code above so i could see how it works

Comment: Ralph, it was just a sample ... for sure if you want to check the abox control on blur then you should use the abox.ClientID. Then the validation occurs on the full page and then will provide you during the for-each loop all controls that fails to validation. If you have trouble you can also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969465/problem-with-page-clientvalidate or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486620/page-clientvalidate-object-expected-error-cant-find-the-validator